# HTML & JavaScript - can't unmute html5 video

Tags: javascript, html, html5-video

I got a very annoying problem. I try for a few hours to unmute an HTML5 video with a 'muted' flag, but all that I try doesn't work.

```
$("#video_background").prop('muted', false);
```

Sadly, that doesn't work, and removing the **muted** prop from the  code makes nothing, the video stays muted. **Is there any solution to force a unmute from the video?**

Or can anyone say what I'm making wrong? `<section>` creates the `<video></video>` for me, so it uses a few classes. But I searched for a "muted" and no class has it, but the video still has no audio on the website.

And yes.. The videos have sound.
My video has **autoplay**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most browsers block any audio that is played by a web page and is not related to user interaction (see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Media/Autoplay_guide). Maybe that's your problem?

Answer (score -3):

You can unmute your html5 video by unmute attribute also, check this out:-

```
<video src="any video" **unmute**></video>
```